# Invalid literal for int() with Base 10''

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I tried to build this simple code to try to guess a number:

```
y = raw_input()
print type(y)
x = int('y')
print type(x)
if x > 0:
    print 'positive'
    if x > 10:
        print 'Greater than 10'
    else:
        print 'less than 10'

elif x == 0:
   print 'equals 0'

print 'Conditionals are over'
print 'Bye Bye'
```

However, running the code in windows powershell, it displays an error:

> ```
> Value error in line 11, stating Invalid literal for int() with Base 10.
> ```

What does that mean and how can it be fixed?

Comment: I am guessing you havent posted all your code, basically you are trying to convert a string into an int (int("y)), use int (y) instead,

Comment: `x=int('y')` passes *a string* with value `'y'` into the `int()` function. Note the contrast with the `type()` call, where you pass in the `y` variable instead.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to convert the char `y` into a int, not the variable named `y` to int

Replace `x=int('y')` with `x=int(y)` and try again

Answer (score 1):

```
y=raw_input()
print type(y)
x=int(y) # < -- Do not pass y as string. 'y' ==> y
print type(x)
if x>0:
    print 'positive'
    if x>10:
        print 'Greater than 10'
    else:
        print 'less than 10'

elif x==0:
   print 'equals 0'

print 'Conditionals are over'
print 'Bye Bye'
```

You are trying to convert `char` to `int` here, due to which **Invalid literal for int() with Base 10** error is thrown. Strings / char can be converted to `int` only when `.isdigit()` is `True`.